# Outlook.invalid_request: The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've tried to connect outlook registration to my web app..I've tried all endpoints, but it still has issue 'invalid_request: The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The expected value is a URI which matches a redirect URI registered for this client application.' Localhost works fine, problem only with remote server.

https://{domain_name}/auth/outlook/login/callback

https://{domain_name}/auth

https://{domain_name}/auth/outlook

https://{domain_name}/auth/outlook/login

https://{domain_name}/V1/auth/outlook/login/callback

https://{domain_name}/V1/auth

https://{domain_name}/V1/auth/outlook

https://{domain_name}/V1/auth/outlook/login